# Unable to change brightness on lock sccreen

Tags: brightness, lock-screen

When at the lock screen, I am unable to adjust the brightness.  This is particularly annoying if the screen is completely off (to save battery) and then locks automatically.  You then have a black screen where the only thing that works is to type in your password and hit enter.